# How to show/hide columns based on value of SharePoint choice check box

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, js

I am working with SharePoint online and in one of the lists, I am using a choice check box column called 'Vehicle Type' with following choices: Personal Vehicle, Company Vehicle.

I am looking to do a simple thing, when Personal vehicle is checked, then I would like to hide two currency columns: Car Rental, Fuel and if Company Vehicle is checked I want to show the above two columns. Can someone help me with the JS solution. Thanks in advance.

P.S: it should account for the change event.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()

    $("input[title='Vehicle Driven']").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")=="Personal Vehicle"){
            $("nobr:contains('Fuel')").closest('tr').hide();
        }else{
            $("nobr:contains('Fuel')").closest('tr').show();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using the classic or modern UI? If modern, JS is not recommended. I would check out the options to customize the form with PowerApps.

Comment: I am using classic only.

Comment: Then see my answer below.

Comment: Check this [Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection in SharePoint using Jquery](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/) [Show / Hide fields based on a drop down field using SPUtility.js](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)

Comment: Also, make sure that you have enabled the custom script as mentioned [here](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create a test custom list and add new column 'Vehicle Type'(choice Checkbox field type) with following choices: Personal Vehicle, Company Vehicle.
And two currency columns: Car Rental, Fuel.

Then add the following code into script editor web part in newform.aspx page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("nobr:contains('Car Rental')").closest('tr').hide();
    $("nobr:contains('Fuel')").closest('tr').hide();
    $("span[title='Personal Vehicle']>input").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("nobr:contains('Car Rental')").closest('tr').hide();
            $("nobr:contains('Fuel')").closest('tr').hide();
        }    
    });
    $("span[title='Company Vehicle']>input").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("nobr:contains('Car Rental')").closest('tr').show();
            $("nobr:contains('Fuel')").closest('tr').show();
        }else{
            $("nobr:contains('Car Rental')").closest('tr').hide();
            $("nobr:contains('Fuel')").closest('tr').hide();
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead, `input`, try to use `select` as the following

```
$("select[title='Vehicle Driven']").change(function()
{
  if ($("select[title='Vehicle Driven']").val() != "Personal Vehicle")
  {
   $("nobr:contains('Fuel')").closest('tr').hide();
  }
  else
  {
   $("nobr:contains('Fuel')").closest('tr').show(); 
  }
// your code
}
```

> Note: In SharePoint Online, make sure that you have [enabled the
>   `custom script`](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

For more details check

- [Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection in SharePoint using Jquery](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)
- [Show / Hide fields based on a drop-down field using SPUtility.js](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a field value with jQuery, you could do something like this (sample is for a text input field)

```
$("input[title='title_of_the_field']").val()
```

And hiding an input field would be something like:

```
$("input[title='title_of_the_field']").hide()
```

And to check if a checkbox is checked, you could use the following code:

```
if ($("input[title='title_of_the_field']").is(":checked"))
{
  // it is checked
}
```

Comment: I added piece of code I am using in the Question description but can't get it to work, can you please take a look and help me out.